# cross-origin resource sharing error: headerdisallowedbypreflightresponse

Tags: asp.net-web-api, cors

I have an extjs front end that connects to a .net webapi2 and am getting the following error.

cross-origin resource sharing error: headerdisallowedbypreflightresponse

I have this in the webapi

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
        //These headers are handling the "pre-flight" OPTIONS call sent by the browser
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With,Content-Type");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
```

does anyone know how to fix?  I can't tell if its something thats wrong in my front end or backend.

[image]

Comment: In your browser's Network tab, inspect the `Access-Control-Request-Headers` header of the preflight request. For things to work, ll the values listed there must also be listed in the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header of the preflight response.

Comment: Besides, I urge you to rely on a CORS library rather than implementing CORS yourself by manually setting headers.

Comment: thanks @jub0bs, in chrome developer tools, where do I see the headers of preflight request?

Comment: has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Comment: i just updated post... is that what you mean?

Comment: it worked!  on server I added a field that was missing.  thank you!